# If $X$ is a $n$ by $k$ real matrix, and we know that $X^{T}X$ is invertible, is $X$ invertible as well?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

If $X$ is a $n$ by $k$ real matrix, and we know that $X^{T}X$ is invertible, we know that $rank(X^{T}X) = n$ by $n$. Can we say that $X$ is invertible as well and hence has rank $n$? thanks!

Comment: The Matrix is not invertible in the sense of matrix inversion, but still $X$ is injective, and thus invertible in the sense of a linear map. (Note that the inverse is only defined on the range of $X$.)

Answer (score 0):

$$\bf X=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\,:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2\\{\bf X}^T\bf X=I:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R $$
But X is not surjective so has no right inverse.

Answer (score -1):

No, if I understand the question right, it is not possible to say that $\mathbf{X} $ is invertible and also $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ is only invertible when $\mathbf{X}$ has full column rank. In that case, you can find the Moore Penrose pseudo inverse of $\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: If $X^TX$ has full rank, what do you know about the rank of $X$? might it be full?

Comment: In that case you can say that $\mathbf{X}$ is full column rank, e.g it has rank $k$ for n by k tall matrix.

Comment: No, it has rank $n\leq k$. $X^{T}X$ has full rank equal to $n$. Assume $X$ itself would have rank less than $n$, then you would easily get a contradiction: Application of a linear map (in this case $X^T$) can not increase the dimension. Thus you can also infer that $k\geq n$ in the case of this question. The column- and the row-rank of a matrix coincide. the rank of the $k\times n$ matrix $X$ can not be bigger than $\min\left(k,n\right)$.

Comment: yes, that is true, if the rank is less than $\min(k,n)$, $\mathbf{X}$ is not invertible and neither is $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$.